# Problem resizing QTabWidget according to tab content (PyQT)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I know there are some answers provided regarding the QTabWidget resize ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710003/force-qt-pyqt-pyside-qtabwidget-to-resize-to-active-tab), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697437/how-can-i-resize-a-qtabwidget), and others); however, I can't get it working properly in my application.

The idea is to create a window that resizes according to the QTabWidget size. Currently, I have two tabs, and the first one has a smaller size compared with the other one.

When I press the second tab, the window size increases as intended but, if I go back to the first tab, the window doesn't shrink. I tried changing the QSizePolicy of each tab as well as resizing the tab and the window but it doesn't change the outcome.

How can I solve the fact the window doesn't shrink? Here is the code:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QSizePolicy,
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QTabWidget,
    QDesktopWidget,
    QRadioButton,
    QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QGridLayout,
    QWidget,
)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupMainUi()
    
    def setupMainUi(self):
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        main_window_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(main_window_layout)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.loadTab1(), "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.loadTab2(), "Tab2")

        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.updateSizes)
        self.updateSizes(0)
        
        main_window_layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def updateSizes(self, index):
            
        for i in range(self.tabs.count()):
            if i != index:
                self.tabs.widget(i).setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        
        self.tabs.widget(index).setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.tabs.widget(index).resize(self.tabs.widget(index).minimumSizeHint())
        self.tabs.widget(index).adjustSize()
        self.resize(self.minimumSize())
        self.adjustSize()
   
    def loadTab1(self):
        
        self.ticketTab = QWidget()
        self.ticketTab.setEnabled(False)

        date_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.ticket = QLabel("Number:", self)
        self.ticket_number = QLineEdit()
        self.ticket_number.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        date_layout.addWidget(self.ticket, 0, 0)
        date_layout.addWidget(self.ticket_number, 0, 1)
        
        self.ticketTab.setLayout(date_layout)
        
        return self.ticketTab 
    
    def loadTab2(self):
        
        self.familyTab = QWidget()
        self.familyTab.setEnabled(False)
        
        family_default_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.family_default_checkbox = QRadioButton("Default")
        self.family_default_checkbox.setChecked(True)
        self.family_default_checkbox.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft) 
        family_default_layout.addWidget(self.family_default_checkbox, alignment = Qt.AlignRight)
        
        family_layout = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.family_label = QLabel("Number of Families:", self)
        self.family_number = QLineEdit()
        self.family_number.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.family_number.textChanged.connect(lambda:self.checkInput(self.family_number))
        family_layout.addWidget(self.family_label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        family_layout.addWidget(self.family_number, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        family_default_layout.addLayout(family_layout)
        
        temp_family_layout = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.family_label_1 = QLabel("Number of Families:", self)
        self.family_number_1 = QLineEdit()
        self.family_number_1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        temp_family_layout.addWidget(self.family_label_1, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        temp_family_layout.addWidget(self.family_number_1, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        family_default_layout.addLayout(temp_family_layout)
        
        min_sub_family_layout = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.min_subfamily_label = QLabel("Minimum Number of SubFamilies:", self)
        self.min_subfamily_number = QLineEdit()
        self.min_subfamily_number.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        min_sub_family_layout.addWidget(self.min_subfamily_label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        min_sub_family_layout.addWidget(self.min_subfamily_number, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        family_default_layout.addLayout(min_sub_family_layout)
        
        max_sub_family_layout = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.max_subfamily_label = QLabel("Maximum Number of SubFamilies:", self)
        self.max_subfamily_number = QLineEdit()
        self.max_subfamily_number.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        max_sub_family_layout.addWidget(self.max_subfamily_label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        max_sub_family_layout.addWidget(self.max_subfamily_number, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        family_default_layout.addLayout(max_sub_family_layout)
        
        self.familyTab.setLayout(family_default_layout)
        
        return self.familyTab
    
os.chdir("../..")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()

qr = win.frameGeometry()
cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
qr.moveCenter(cp)
win.move(qr.topLeft()) 
win.move(win.pos().x(), win.pos().y() - 180)

win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Sorry for the simple question. Only recently I have been exploring PyQT.

Answer (score 1):

QTabWidget is based on [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html), which always uses the biggest size hint of all pages.

In order to avoid that, you can override both `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint` and ensure that it only returns the *current* widget hint.

Then, since resizing require some internal event handling, you can ensure that the application does that by calling `processEvents()` and *then* call adjustSize.

```
class ResizingTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.currentChanged.connect(self.updateGeometry)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()

    def sizeHint(self):
        current = self.currentWidget()
        if not current:
            return super().sizeHint()
        return current.sizeHint()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def setupMainUi(self):
        # ...
        self.tabs = ResizingTabWidget()
        # ...

    def updateSizes(self):
        QApplication.processEvents()
        self.adjustSize()
```

Note that you don't need to call `updateSizes` in the `__init__`.
Also, be aware that from the UX perspective this is not a very good approach, as UIs that continuously resize themselves are considered annoying by many and often confuse the user.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I try adding the solution but the issue still happens. The window is resized when tab1 -> tab2 but the same doesn't happen when tab1 is resumed. I noticed in your answer you don't change the QSizePolicy. Isn't this necessary? Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira you're not trying to add your code to `updateSizes`, right? It should only have the two lines specified above. Also, the size policies shouldn't be altered for this.

Comment: @musicamante Where is `updateSizes` called?

Comment: @UmbralReaper when the `tab` QTabWidget sends its `currentChanged` signal, see the original code.

Comment: @musicamante That makes sense. I do admit that I tend to glaze over large blocks of code.